# How to handle table column of type that is not known in Java (Spring Data)?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, postgis

I have a table with a column of type `geography(Point,4326)` (using PostGIS).
I only need to use this column in the WHERE condition when querying the table. E.g. in the query below, `geog` is the name of that column.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT pois.*\n" +
        "FROM pois,\n" +
        "(select ST_MakePoint(:lat,:lon)::geography as poi) as poi\n" +
        "WHERE ST_DWithin(geog, poi, 400)\n" +
        "ORDER BY ST_Distance(geog, poi)", nativeQuery = true)
public List<PointOfInterest> getPOIsAroundLocation(@Param("lat") double lat,
                                                   @Param("lon") double lon);
```

However, in the entity class `PointOfInterest`, I don't know how to map that column, since I don't have a Java type equivalent to the `geography(Point,4326)` database type.

If I don't mention the column at all in the class, it won't be created in the database (I have `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`), and the query will fail.

What can I do? Is there a way to create a column with a java type (maybe `Object`?) and then map it to the db type with some annotation? Or is there a way to tell Spring Data about the db column without actually adding a field I won't use in the class?

Here is the `PointOfInterest` class:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "pois")
public abstract class PointOfInterest {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private final double latitude;
    private final double longitude;
    private final PoiType poiType;

    public PointOfInterest() {
        this.latitude = this.longitude = 0;
        poiType = null;
    }

    public PointOfInterest(double latitude, double longitude, PoiType poiType) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.poiType = poiType;
    }
}
```

Comment: A start could be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22186506 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314732.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I found out about hibernate-spatial from the comment of @Pilosa, I added some dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
    <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

And I added a `org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point` field in the Entity class to map the geography column.

```
@JsonIgnore
@Column(columnDefinition = "geography(Point,4326)")
private Point geog;
```

The `@JsonIgnore` annotation is because jackson threw a stack overflow exception when trying to deserialize the field (see related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59291785/error-de-serializing-geometry-with-jackson)). This solution worked for me since I only use the point for querying, and I don't need its value.